# Sneezing volume etiquette

Tags: professionalism

One of my coworkers always sneezes loudly, to the point that it startles those around her (including myself). She claims to not be able to help it. I know I can control my volume, but maybe some people really can't. It's almost comical (to me), but brings up a question of etiquette.

What is the workplace etiquette for the volume at which someone sneezes?

Comment: About how many times does this happen per day? Also keep in mind some people sneeze more often/loudly during allergy seasons. I've never had a problem with this but have worked with people who do. Closing the windows if they're open may help in that case, or finding out from that person if she can be made more comfortable.

Comment: I can't exactly control the volume of my sneeze, so I enforce it in an other way: pinch my nose and cover my nose-mouth area with a tissue. Brings down the volume a lot, also prevents stuff flying out of that region :)

Comment: She generally sneezes about once a day. Maybe a little more during allergy season. She also blows her nose very loudly. I don't think she can control it.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts While not as dangerous as some say it is, stifling a sneeze isn't recommended.  http://m.livescience.com/32776-is-it-safe-to-hold-in-a-sneeze.html

Comment: Maybe she cannot control the volume of the sneeze but she can to in the other room to blow her nose.

Comment: If it's only once per day then the proper thing to do is not to say anything.

Comment: If her sneezes startle you I think the only thing you can do is maybe playfully ask her to alert you guys when she's feeling a sneeze coming.

Comment: I know my sneezes are generally quite loud.  They usually come out of nowhere, and given the speed and force, control is the last thing on my mind at the moment.  What's on my mind is making sure no one is in the blast area.  I'm sure she's as embarrassed about this as you are unhappy with the sudden interruption.  So, be kind and try to put this small thing on ignore.

Answer (score 4):

This seemed like a fairly reasonable set of resources on sneezing:

http://www.livescience.com/32707-why-do-some-people-sneeze-so-loud.html

http://lifehacker.com/5897392/learn-to-quiet-your-high-volume-sneezes#

I'm not a sneeze scientist or anything - but it seems like there are cases where people *can't* control all aspects of a sneeze, but there's a bottom line expectation that an individual can control enough to avoid covering his or her coworkers in bacteria.

Expectations I've seen on stuff like this in workplaces:

- A person should always take reasonable precautions in keeping their coworkers healthy - in particular - covering the face when sneezing and staying home when you know you are really sick
- A person should be prepared to address any frequently repeated behavior that is very annoying.  Sneezing loudly once and a great while is reasonable, sneazing loudly every hour or two is likely to be annoying.